# Difference between HttpContext.Current.Response/Request And Page.Request/Response

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please, can you explain me what is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Response/Request And Page.Request/Response.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None whatsoever.

The latter is shorthand for the former.

It's especially convenient when writing ASPX pages; because these pages inherit `Page`, you can just write `Request` or `Response`.

Similarly, `Page.Context` is short for `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 3):

- If we take a look at the `System.Web.UI.Page` and take a look at property Request we see it retrieves the HttpContext for the request page.
- Now if we look at the `HttpContext.Current.Request` we see that it "Gets or sets the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request."

So they are really just the same thing, you can just call them through different classes.
[System.web.HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) 
[System.web.ui.page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The properties points to same object, there is no difference.